# What data type can save latest 20 values in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a data type where I can save latest 20 values in it?

Maybe just like Code A

**Code A**

```
val myData: ADateType<Int>(20)

myData.add(1)
myData.add(2)
...
myData.add(20)
myData.add(21)

val result1=myData.getList //It will return 2,3,4,...20,21

myData.add(22)
myData.add(23)

val result2=myData.getList //It will return 4,5,6...22,23
```

Comment: Like an array? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library doesn’t have a class specifically for this. You can use CircularFifoQueue from [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

[Here’s a basic tutorial.](https://www.baeldung.com/commons-circular-fifo-queue)

Or here's a basic implementation of a CircularList. I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
class CircularList<T> private constructor(maxSize: Int, private val backingList: LinkedList<T>) :
    MutableList<T> by backingList {

    constructor(maxSize: Int) : this(maxSize, LinkedList())

    var maxSize: Int = maxSize
        set(value) {
            field = value
            enforceSize()
        }

    private fun enforceSize() {
        repeat(backingList.size - maxSize) {
            backingList.removeFirst()
        }
    }

    override fun add(element: T): Boolean {
        backingList.add(element)
        enforceSize()
        return true
    }

    override fun add(index: Int, element: T) {
        backingList.add(element)
        enforceSize()
    }

    override fun addAll(index: Int, elements: Collection<T>): Boolean {
        backingList.addAll(index, elements)
        enforceSize()
        return true
    }

    override fun addAll(elements: Collection<T>): Boolean {
        backingList.addAll(elements)
        enforceSize()
        return true
    }

    override fun iterator(): MutableIterator<T> = listIterator()

    override fun listIterator(): MutableListIterator<T> = listIterator(0)

    override fun listIterator(index: Int): MutableListIterator<T> {
        val backingIterator = backingList.listIterator(index)
        var size = size
        return object: MutableListIterator<T> by backingIterator {

            override fun remove() {
                size--
                backingIterator.remove()
            }

            override fun add(element: T) {
                if (++size > maxSize) {
                    val place = nextIndex()
                    while (hasPrevious()) previous()
                    remove()
                    while (nextIndex() < place - 1) next()
                }
                backingIterator.add(element)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean = backingList == other

    override fun hashCode(): Int = backingList.hashCode()

    override fun toString(): String = backingList.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to instance `class CircularList<T>` ?  and `val my=CircularList<Int>()` is wrong. and more how is  the parameter `maxSize` passed?

Comment: BTW, Android Studio prompt `constructor(maxSize: Int) : this(maxSize, LinkedList())` can be removed in your code.

Comment: Pass the max size to the constructor. It works just like your requested sample code. `val list = circularList<Int>(20)`. It won’t work if you remove one of the constructors. If you’re confused about how it works, I suggest reading about delegation and about secondary constructors in the Kotlin documentation.

Comment: The primary constructor is private and the secondary constructor is public so you are forced to use the secondary constructor. This allows the class to ensure it is using a LinkedList as its backing list. It has to be done with a secondary constructor because a delegate has to be fulfilled by a primary constructor parameter, but we don’t want to expose a way for an arbitrary list instance to be passed as that parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works well, it'my problem

Comment: And more, `What version of Kotlin are you using? I did not get that prompt.`, now my Android Studio doesn't display the prompt.

Comment: See the updated code. I just realized that if you added an item using the MutableIterator, then it wouldn't automatically remove the oldest value if necessary. I tried creating a kind of hacky MutableIterator that works properly, but I haven't tested it. If you don't modify your collection through the iterator, this doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

collection don't have custom limite, but you can write a class to control the size of collection, like this

```
class ADateType<E>() {
    private val mList = mutableListOf<E>()
    private val mMaxSize = 20

    fun add(element: E) {
        if (mList.size>=mMaxSize)
            mList.removeAt(0)

        mList.add(element)
    }

    fun toList(): List<E> {
        return mList.toList()
    }
}
```

The result is someting like this

```
fun main() {
    val list = ADateType<Int>()
    list.add(1)
    list.add(2)
...
    list.add(20)
    list.add(21)
    list.add(22)

    
    println(list.toList())  //It will return 3,4,5,6...21,22
}
```